# Finding the 10 nearest points in 3D Euclidean space, for EACH element in a 5-million element catalog

Tags: python, sorting, machine-learning, distance, euclidean-distance

Suppose I have a catalog of 5 million points, with their x,y,z location in 3D space. For EACH of these 5 million points, I want to find the 10 points closest to it (straightforward 3D Euclidean distance formula).

In python, if I do a simple for loop over every element in the table, and within the for loop do an array operation (not a second for loop!) to find the distance between the current point and all other points in the catalog, this would take days/weeks. I've tried some stuff involving sorting and computing the distance between points only +/- a couple thousand rows around each table element, but that would still take days.

What is a faster way to do this in python? Is there a way to turn the for loop into some kind of vectorized operation? Would any machine learning techniques (e.g., in scikit-learn) be helpful? Or would somehow parallelizing the code help?

Comment: Given the dimensionality of your data, i.e. 3d euclidian space, trying to find the 10 closest neighbors, it sounds like a great candidate for [spatial partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search#Space_partitioning), which involves putting your data into a kd-tree, which can give you really good performance! `scikit-learn` has a kd-tree implementation already. This approach has the added bonus of being *exact* instead of approximate.

Answer (score 1):

I've used a packaged called RANN in R that finds "Approximate" nearest neighbors.  I ran it in a few minutes with 25 M observations and 8 dimensions, and the results were good enough for my use case.

I'm not sure if there is a Python version of the package I used, but I found this link that has a lot of alternatives:  [Benchmark of ANN Libraries](https://erikbern.com/2015/07/04/benchmark-of-approximate-nearest-neighbor-libraries.html)

[Benchmark of ANN Libraries](https://erikbern.com/2015/07/04/benchmark-of-approximate-nearest-neighbor-libraries.html)